# Publish or Un publish any comment

Tags: comments

How to give moderator a right to publish or unpublish/edit any comment , not just own comment or  comment on own content without giving "Administer comments and comment settings" Permission, by giving just a tab for publish and unpublish for appropriate role ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to /admin/people/permissions and check assign the appropriate permission("Administer comments and comment settings") you'd like to the that role.
Check https://www.drupal.org/node/777696

Comment: If giving Administer ... comment settings is not wanted then blocking that path via [Custom Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_perms) from moderator can enhance this solution.

Comment: I wanted to ask it that can be done without giving "Administer comments and comment settings" by giving just a tab for publish and unpublish  for appropriate role?

Comment: Can This be done through flag with flag only visible to particular role? and that role can see all unpublished comments visible to only that role?

Comment: I do not really understand what you aim for.  What is a flag? What do you mean by tab?

Comment: By tab i mean a link , by flag https://www.drupal.org/project/flag , I just want to give easy link for publishing and unpublishing a comment  for moderator.

Comment: You can also add a link like "comment/%/approve", where "%" holds the comment id. You can add the link within hook_form_FORMID_alter(). You need to implement the callback on your own. This will require access check both on the addition of the html in the form and the callback. Hope that helps.